# Returning More Than One Object in a Function - a Tidy Chisq.Test Tibble and Ggplot

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(ggmosaic)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
library(tibble)
```

Using the code below, I would like the function to output both the tidy tibble as well as the ggplot. I'm not sure how to use "return" within a function to return more than one thing.

I tried something like this...

```
Chifun<-function(var){ 
df<-happy%>%select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)%>% 
map(~chisq.test(.x,happy[,var]))%>% 
tibble(names=names(.),data=.)%>%
mutate(stats=map(data,tidy))%>%unnest(stats)
GG<-ggplot(df)+ geom_col(aes_string(x="names",y="p.value"))
return(df,GG)}
```

...as well as this...

```
Chifun<-function(var){
df<-happy%>%select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall)%>% map(~chisq.test(.x,happy[,var]))
%>%tibble(names=names(.),data=.)%>%
mutate(stats=map(data,tidy))%>%unnest(stats)
return(df)
GG<-function(var){ggplot(df)+
geom_col(aes_string(x="names",y="p.value"))
return(GG)
}
}
```

I've tried a few other variations, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your first example code you can return a list with `df` and `GG`: `return(list(df = df, GG = GG))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to return more than one item use a list:

```
Chifun<-function(var){ 
df<-happy %>% select(-id,-year,-age,-wtssall) %>% 
map(~chisq.test(.x,happy[,var])) %>% 
tibble(names=names(.),data=.) %>%
mutate(stats=map(data,tidy))%>%unnest(stats)

GG<-ggplot(df)+ geom_col(aes_string(x="names",y="p.value"))

return( list(dfrm = df,plotGG = GG) ) }
```